# A WP website we are developing is resulting too slow for first visitor.. Any ideas..?

Tags: wordpress, performance

We purchased a WP theme and did some customized changes in php and html 
to bring the design where we wanted...
We are almost done with the design of the website and construction 
and we are about to deliver to client 
but for some reason the website is responding very slow on the first visitor.. 
and we cannot find the problem, what conflicts with what..

Are there any WP experts in here that could have a look and maybe identify the problem..?

Thank you in advance..

[Click here to view the website](http://www.royal-range.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple issues behind a slow wp website:

- Using multiple plugins can slow down a wp website.
- A poor web server that is not able to respond quickly.
- Some configuration issues.

[image]

What i can see is that your website is resource intensive, CSS and JS script files are too heavy, even heavier than all images on the home page.

**Try:**

> Minify the css and js files.
>
> Compress images and the size would come down to less than 1 mb (use tinypng.com)

Use [Google page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to see the flow of the resources of your website and other related details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your observations..  We'll give those a try and come back here hopefully with good results.

Answer (score 0):

- Enable gzip compression
- Leverage browser caching
- Optimize images
- Defer parsing of JavaScript
- Minify CSS, JS

Analyze your site using [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com) and [Google PageSpeed Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), and follow the recommendations that you get from this systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that slow? I can get a directory listing from your wp-includes directory [just fine](http://www.royal-range.com/wp-includes/). Joking aside, looks like there are two different versions of jquery being loaded in, that's never good for things (view source, line:435) and the homepage makes about 179 requests which is a bit bonkers.

Try a caching plugin. As others have said better configured hosting helps, especially those that use caching technologies such as varnish/redis. A CDN will help with geographic speed. Compress images with WP Smush or similar. Good luck!